# Upgrading from version 4 to 5

Tags: upgrading, 5

On the server I am hosting my website, PHP was upgraded to a newer version which is not supported by Drupal version 4.
There is a script and a description for doing the upgrade in Drupal version 5, but this script does not run with the new version of PHP either.
Is there any other possibility to upgrade?